# Unexpected "Cache entry must specify a value for Size when SizeLimit is set" message in AspNetCore 3

Tags: asp.net-core, memorycache

So this all worked fine before updating to AspNetCore 3 today.

I am using a memory cache with dependency injection (`IMemoryCache cache`).

I add it to my middleware with `services.AddMemoryCache();`
 and do NOT set  a size, but I still end up with the error message:

> Cache entry must specify a value for Size when SizeLimit is set.

When I inspect the instance of `MemoryCache` and it does indeed have a size of `10240` set (see image).

The problem is I've been looking for a hour and I have no clue where this was set. Nowhere in my code do I have `SizeLimit` or `10240` anywhere - including config files.

It seems to have started when I switched to using `app.UseEndpoints` instead of `app.UseMvc()` - but I've made so many changes I'm not sure.

Where could this possibly be set that is elluding me.?

[image]

Comment: OK so it appears to be EF Core that's doing it, but still not clear what the solution is - https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/master/src/EFCore/Infrastructure/EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.cs

Comment: What is the defination for `_cache`? Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? I fail to reproduce your issue with `services.AddMemoryCache()` and `IMemoryCache cache`. I would suggest you try to check whether this issue exist with Asp.Net Core 3.0 template and IMemoryCahche.

Comment: @_cache is just an injected IMemoryCache. It turns out there’s a note in the MSDN docs that say if you use EF Core it basically breaks memory cache (slight liberty taken in my paraphrasing). I’ll update it when I get a chance.

Comment: See also https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12905

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I managed to stop this exception from being thrown by removing the call to `AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()` from my `ConfigureServices()` method in `Startup.cs`:

```
public class Startup
{
   ...

   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
      ...

      services
         .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer() // <-- Removed this
         .AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(...)
         )

      ...
   }

   ...
}
```

Apparently calling `AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()` [is no longer needed in EF Core 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.sqlserverservicecollectionextensions.addentityframeworksqlserver?view=efcore-3.0):

> Calling this method is no longer necessary when building most applications, including those that use dependency injection in ASP.NET or elsewhere.

Thanks to **@Simon_Weaver** for his clue about EF Core!

Comment: this solved my problem !! 

just for curiosity, could someone explain why these things are related to each other ?!?

Comment: @MarPinello EF Core sets up MemoryCache with a SizeLimit here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/661475efd144e5e5cf9f028cbca7e43045018ac1/src/EFCore/Infrastructure/EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.cs#L270 this method is in turn called by AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/2ff3db33660c59e35d449dcbddd8d37dfba72b7b/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Extensions/SqlServerServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L91 . So when you go to initialise the MemoryCache without SizeLimit, the SizeLimit is already set.

Comment: The same applies to `services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()` when using PostgreSQL. Thanks!